# How do I navigate from a React Child route back to a parent

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

In my application, I have a blog *module*. When the route matches '/blog' the Blog Root component is rendered according to:

```
<Route path="/blog" component={BlogRoot} />
```

Within this component there is a child router as:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:slug`} component={BlogPost} />
    <Route path={match.path} exact component={BlogListing} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I am having trouble navigating back from the BlogPost Component (which matches `${match.path}/:slug`) back to the listing (the one matching `path={match.path} exact`). When on the Blog Post route, using a `Link to="/blog"` does not render the Blog Listing component (it stays on the current BlogPost).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you have to use single BrowserRouter in the project
The second moment change the order of your routes in Switch. First  `path={match.path} exact` and then `path={${match.path}/:slug}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is staying at the same component is, it is unable to find the next route.
For this you need to define your dynamic routes (`/:slug`) first and then use your component route.